# OpenThread() through different thread numbers ?

Tags: delphi

I'm confusing about opening different threads with OpenThread Function and examining them with `NtQueryInformationThread` native function .
I have no problem with `NtQueryInformationThread` & I can examine them finely.
the problem is I don't know how to loop through different number of threads using `OpenThread` 
(with SetDebugPrivilege Consideration) .
suppose we have different threads from number 5100 to 5200 & we want to examine them sequentially : for example 5100, 5101, 5102, 5103, 5104, 5105 ... 5200 ... .
I don't know how to use `OpenThread` Function in delphi in right way ... .
I'm using this syntax & I found it wrong :

```
OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,false,(DWORD)5100)
```

.
if anyone could guide me how to use OpenThread though different number of threads it would be great .

thanks alot .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how'd you get threads with stricly sequential IDs, cause Windows doesn't (have to) assing thread IDs in any pattern.
If you want to loop through a set of threads, you'll have to  use the Tool Help API:

1. call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0)` to get system state snapshot
2. loop through the threads with `Thread32First` and `Thread32Next` and select the threads you want to work with (eg. by its process' ID)
3. use `OpenThread` with an appropriate access mask, eg. `THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION`
    
   do NOT use `THREAD_ALL_ACCESS` unless you created the thread in the current process and you know exactly what you're doing
   (restrain yourself to read-only access, if you touch threads of another process)
4. do what you want to, eg. call `NtQueryInformationThread`
5. don't forget `CloseHandle`

You have to handle the possibility of any of the threads terminating (and being replaced with a new thread with the same ID) as long as you don't hold the threads handle.

**Edit** (further clarification by request)
The `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` with `dwFlags == TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD` gives you a system-wide snapshot  (the `th32ProcessID` argument is ignored in this case) of all threads *existing* in the moment, regardless of their state, and the `THREADENTRY32` structure subsequently returned by `Thread32[First|Next]` contains the `th32ThreadID` and `th32OwnerProcessID` fields, which you can use to identify the thread.